# pyautogui.moveTo() not working in windows

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate my mouse movements using `pyautogui` but it's not working.
Here's the code I used:

```py
join_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/sanjay/OneDrive/Desktop/zoom automation/pics for pyautogui/join_button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_btn)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click()
```

I have installed python and added it to path too but nothing seems to work.
I have installed the pyautogui package using this code:

```sh
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

Other code like `pyautogui.click()` and `time.sleep()` do work good but only `pyautogui.moveTo()` is not working.
I tried using `pyautogui.move()` instead of `pyautogui.moveTo()` but the mouse cursor goes to random locations and clicks.
I have absolutely no idea what to do now.
Please help.

Comment: Can you describe **how** it's not working? Be specific about what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Have you verified that `locateCenterOnScreen` is returning good coordinates? Are you in any way interacting with the mouse while this code is running?

Comment: So what I expect it to do is move the mouse cursor to the join button and then click it. But it's not moving at all.

Comment: Are you sure that your coordinates for the button are correct?

Comment: I have not put any coordinates, instead, I have given the path of join button picture for pyautogui to recognize

Comment: The function `locateCenterOnScreen` returns coordinates, which are then used to determine where to move. Is this function returning meaningful coordinates? You won't move to the correct spot if `join_btn` is set to some junk value. Can you check to see what value it's getting set to?

Comment: If I enter the coordinates, will it work? (I am new to pyautogui)

Comment: It will move (or attempt to move) to the coordinates you provide. I cannot answer whether this will be what you want or not. But if the cursor is not moving or not moving to where you want, the first thing you'll want to do is to check what's being passed to `pyautogui.moveTo`

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. How do I know the coordinates of where my cursor is right now? Is there any command for that?

Comment: I'd recommend you do some reading of the [pyautogui documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/). Especially the sections on [mouse control functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-control-functions), and [the locate functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using `pyautogui.moveTo`, you have to run the script **as administrator**.